# OOP Как внутри класса сделать подсчеты. И вернуть уже готовый результат

Tags: php

У меня есть класс, в котором нужно сделать пару вычислений и вернуть строку.

Все работает. Но приходится вызывать после объявления класса каждый раз новый метод. А  мне это не совсем нравится.

Что порекомендуете?

код Упрощенно вот такой.

```
class Primer {

public $a;
public $b;
public $ctn;
public $OOPS;


public function getA(){
  $this->a;
}

public function getB(){
  $this->b;
}

public function SetA($a){
    $this->a=$a;
    return $this;
}

public function SetB($b){
    $this->b=$b;
    return $this;
}




public function __construct($a,$b)
{
   $this->SetA($a);
   $this->SetB($b);
}

public function Count()
{
    $ctn=$this->a+$this->b;
    return $this->ctn=$ctn;
}

public function Limit(){
    $start=$this->ctn/$this->a;
    $OOPS="$start.$this->b";
    return $OOPS;
}

public function __toString()
{
 return " $this->OOPS";
}
```

}

Динозавр !!

```
$somting=new Primer($a, $b);
$somting->Count();
$somting->Limit();
```

В место этого Днозавра как то отдать Просто стороку.

Comment: А что вы хотите?

Comment: Хочу вызвать (new Primer($a, $b) )->OOPS

Comment: Просто что бы внутри класса все посчиталось и отдло мне готовый результат. в OOPS

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a965b8000f9bdd6fa36aaa9c050ea2dc5b78a68  это?

Comment: @Aлексей, я думаю тогда,  и правда, просто перенести вызовы Count и Limit в конструктор. Судя по `(new Primer($a, $b) )->OOPS`

Comment: @splash58 да, в связи с примером ТС это так....но, кмк, просто должно же что-то триггерить метод подсчета) иначе как-то совсем идиотско))

Comment: а собственно установка в конструкторе а и б - вот он триггер :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не могу понять как не занося в переменную, создать класс и подсчет к нему Вот чтоб так было?
$dump=(new Primer($page, $pageinlist))->Calc();
ноль возвращект!(

Comment: ну сделай rerurn в `Calc()` вместо __toString

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прости не пойму что сделать?? Я тупой!! ПИПЕЦ

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно отделить логику по вычислению и получению значения:

```
public function CalcCount()
{
    $ctn=$this->a+$this->b;

    return $this;
}

public function CalcLimit(){
    $start=$this->ctn/$this->a;
    $OOPS="$start.$this->b";

    return $this;
}

public function GetCount()
{
    return $this->ctn
}

public function GetLimit(){
    return $this->OOPS;
}
```

Тогда можно так писать:

```
$somting=new Primer($a, $b);
$somting->CalcCount()->CalcLimit()->GetLimit();
```

Comment: Это тот же динозавр. А я хочу что бы внутри класса выполнились подсчёты и записались в переменную public $OOPS.
Что бы потом просто вызвать (new Primer($a,$b)->OOPS);

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как работают классы. Почитайте про это.

Comment: Дело в том что просто класс не делает действий по вычислению входных данных. А нужно его заставить внутри класса все это провернуть.

Comment: Тогда он должен сделать это в конструкторе. В PHP есть конструкторы?

Comment: конечно, есть. но я не понимаю, это ли надо автору

Comment: @splash58 да никто не понимает, мне кажется даже сам автор)